# Translate the sentence into symbolic logic

Tags: logic, logic-translation

> You can fool some of the people all of the time, and you can fool all of the people some of the time, but you can't fool all of the people all of the time.

My attempt is

$$((\exists(x),A(x)) \land(\forall(x),S(x))) \land \neg (\forall(x), A(x))$$

Such that

$A(x)=$ You can fool all the time

$S(x)=$ You can fool some of the time

Just starting out basic logic and I'm looking to see where I"m making mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt isn't entirely satisfactory because you ignore the fact that the sentence quantifies over times. Here's a better translation, I think:

$\exists x \forall y Fxy  \ \wedge \exists y \forall x Fxy \ \wedge \neg \forall x \forall y Fxy$.

The interpretation of $Fxy$ is "x is fooled at time y".

Comment: Actually your translation is incorrect. The quote is technically ambiguous but the intent is clearly to say that some people can be ( fooled all the time ) and sometimes you can ( fool all the people ).. so your second clause has the quantifiers the wrong way.

Comment: @user21820 That wasn't how I was thinking about the second clause, but on second thought, I agree that your suggested reading in this more natural one. I've edited the post.

Comment: Yea it's a pity people didn't invent brackets in natural language. =)

Comment: By the way, the proper way to capture the typing correctly is to either use restricted quantifiers if you have some kind of type theory or to have separate predicates $P,T$ for people and times, for example the first clause would be "$\exists x\ ( P(x) \land \forall y\ ( T(y) \to F(x,y) ) )$".